# Information about remote IP addresses

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming

I want to track all IP addresses with which my computer is communicating. I am using C# and Visual Studio. There is one listBox in which I will put all remote IP address. I am new to network programming so I need some direction about that kind of problem.

My question is how to do this? How to get information about remote IP addresses which which my computer make connections?

Comment: Are you sitting behind a router? Or do you have a direct connection to the Internet? Do you care about *remote* servers, or only those on your local network?

Comment: I am using Aolynk Router. For now I just want logic how to get information about any remote IP address whit which my computer get in touch.

Comment: Do you want only the remote addresses connected to your program, or all connections of your computer(like the `netstat` command)

Comment: @Cody why do you think a router is relevant? If the remote host is behind a router you will get the address of his router. But a router on your side of the internet should have no effect.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Strictly speaking, perhaps, it may not be. But the vast majority of routers now have NAT turned on by default (and if not, they *should*). That could definitely complicate things, because it's doing IP address translation beyond the client machine. For example, running `netstat` on the machine I'm sitting at, *everything* is a private IP, even though I'm obviously connected to the Internet.

Comment: @Cody Your computer won't notice the NAT your router does. It only notices the NAT the remote router does. My `netstat` does show public IPs, while I'm behind a router that does NAT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most socket programming applications talk to the TCP socket API that's roughly standardized between operating systems.  If you just want to write a simple server and visualize the clients talking to your server running in your process that's pretty easy.  However, your process can't see the socket connections talking to other processes on your machine with the typical socket API.

If you want to get access to all IPs the entire machine is talking too you'll have to use a lower level API.  That's not standardized between OS.  For Windows I'd look at Winsock API to see if you can find how to look at the tcp/ip stack of the OS.  It gets more complex because TCP connections ride on top of IP packets.  At what level do you want to look at?  Just TCP, or all protocols that also ride on top of IP.  ARP, UDP, TCP, ICMP to name a view standard ones.

If you're just learning then doing just a simple server, and all the connections talking to that server in your process is much simpler.  Going lower is going to be jumping into the deep end quickly.  Not that I'm saying you shouldn't this.  Would you like to keep it simple and stay with the connections your process is talking to, or would you like to go into the deep dark Window's forest?  Choose your adventure.

Edit: Better option for lower level access is WinPcap with a C# wrapper.  That will let you get the raw packet information.  Even let you put your PC in promiscuous mode and sniff all traffic on your subnet not just your PC.

Comment: Not only IP addresses whit which my program is communicating. Every connection on my hole computer. Something like log information about connection activity.

Comment: Well if you're just learning it's easier to do the just your program that's all I'm pointing out.  You'll have to go lower with something like WinPcap or Winsock to see that information.  Or writing a Network Driver Filter that gets inserted into the TCP stack.  The OSI network model has levels so doing your process stays at the application layer at layer 4, the next layer down is TCP,UDP, etc at layer 3, then IP, ARP at layer 2, and ethernet at layer 1 (this is hardware so you can't write software in this level, but you can read from it).  It gets lower level as you go down in the layers.

Answer (score 3):

You could leverage the `netstat` command to get information about which IP addresses and ports your machine is communicating with. You could run this command on a regular basis and parse the text output.

For example, the following command will list the state of all connections including local and remote connection details:

```
C:\Users\chibacity>netstat -a -n

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    10.0.0.107:32495       209.85.229.125:5222    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    10.0.0.107:32507       209.85.229.125:5222    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    10.0.0.107:32520       209.85.229.18:443      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    10.0.0.107:32755       209.85.227.109:993     ESTABLISHED
  //etc...
```

Or if you have admin privilleges you can get executable details too:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> netstat -a -n -b

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    10.0.0.107:32495       209.85.229.125:5222    ESTABLISHED
 [googletalk.exe]
  TCP    10.0.0.107:32507       209.85.229.125:5222    ESTABLISHED
 [chrome.exe]
  TCP    10.0.0.107:32520       209.85.229.18:443      ESTABLISHED
 [chrome.exe]
  TCP    10.0.0.107:32755       209.85.227.109:993     ESTABLISHED
  //etc...
```

You can call this command from .Net using [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) and parse the text output, e.g:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx

Comment: Reliably parsing the text output is close to impossible. It can change with every windows version. And it's localized. On a german windows XP it looks like this: "Aktive Verbindungen

  Proto  Lokale Adresse         Remoteadresse          Status
  TCP    MyComp:4201         123.456.789.123         HERGESTELLT
  TCP    MyComp:4206         stackoverflow.com:http  WARTEND"

Comment: @CodeInChaos I see your point, but describing pulling IP addresses out of that as "close to impossible" is over exaggerating. It would be **easy**. Surely you cannot be serious. The IP address format is not localized.

Comment: I'm exaggerating a bit, but that code won't be very reliable and I'd avoid it in my program if there is any other way.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Again you are exaggerating. All versions of Windows produce an output that can be parsed with a simple Regex. Yes, it's very hacky - I admit that! But it's not that problematic.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, there's an IP helper library, [iphlpapi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366073%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), which can discover information about open connections on your machine. In particular, you want to look at the `GetTcpTable` and `GetUdpTable` functions.

The problem is this is a C API. To use these from C# requires you to use the P/Invoke API. It's a trivial task, but can take some time to do. Each of the C structs used need rewriting in C#, making use of the `System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace to marshal them. Much of this can be automated, or done by decorating struct fields with the correct attributes, but there may be cases where you need to marshal a structure manually.

The C functions you import need marking with `[DllImport("iphlpapi.dll")]` with any other relevant attributes depending on the function you're importing. You can read more about PInvoke at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx), and perhaps find some already written imports at the [pinvoke wiki](http://pinvoke.net/). In addition, there is a tool which can attempt to automate much of it for you, the [Pinvoke interop assitant](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120)

Comment: This is a far cleaner answer than the one accepted!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `ObservableCollection<string> mAccessInfo` somewhere in your code as a publicly visible variable bound to your list, you could place this in the part of the code where you listen for connections:

```
Socket socketForClient = tcpListener.AcceptSocket( );

if (socketForClient.Connected)
{
    mAccessInfo.Add(socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
    //do other stuff...
}
```

Since it's ObservableCollection, on each new connection that enters the list, the list you're bound to is updated.

**Edit**: As Cody Gray pointed out, this won't work if you have IP's in between as proxy/router/NAT etc...